# Joining multiple objects removing internal geometry

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am fairly new to using Blender and I am having trouble performing a particular operation and could use some guidance. I have been creating complex objects by joining multiple overlapping duplicates of a base object. Say like a flower made out of a bunch petals. The only method I have found to quickly remove all internal geometry is to use a boolean modifier intersect+carve with a larger object such as a cube completely surrounding the object. However carve is no longer available in 2.8 and Bmesh is not producing the desired result.

Is there a different approach I can take to produce the same results?

Below is an example of before and after

[image]

[image]

With only two objects it is straightforward to do, but with 5+ all overlapping it becomes overwhelming.

Answer (score 1):

[image: First]

Place the objects together where they will connect

Duplicate the outside object and place it on a different layer for later.

[[image: Join}[2]]

Join both meshes

[image: Intersect]

Go into edit mode, select the outer mesh as shown above, and hit ctrl-F.  From the drop-down, choose "Intersect (Boolean)." Now the mesh which would be inside the joined mesh is deleted.

[image: BooleanModifier]

Now bring the other object which you moved to a different layer back, and join it to the other object using the Boolean Modifier, as shown above.

Hope that is the answer you needed!

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply RBlong2us, I really appreciate it. However, it is not quite what I am looking for. I revised my original post to include some example images to better illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Awe, I see why my method wouldn't be the best for your situation.  Sorry that I can't be of better help.  Good luck.